# How to update a client-side page without js and jquery on django?

Tags: django, python-2.7, static, connection

It is necessary to make a static application that uses a constant connection to the server to receive messages or updates the page in a period of time. With Django, python 2.7 and without js and jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just immediately do a page refresh by adding `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0">` to the  of your page. Then sleep instead of responding until you actually want to update the page.

Thats still a shitty hack and you should propably reconsider your design. Client-Side Updates and no JS doesn't mix.